# Angular 2 how to read Custom error message from backend

Tags: rest, angular, angular2-http

My problem with Angular 2 that was not exist in AngularJS, that I was sending the error message as a string with backend API call in case I have error, with  error status 401 as example, the problem now that I can't read this message from Angular2 http response message, while I can do that from AngularJS:

I tried the following codes and nothing was helpful:

**Promise:**

```
this._http.post('/login',{email: 'email@example.com', password: '123'})
            .toPromise()
            .then((resp) => console.log(resp), (error) => console.log(error));
```

**Observable:**

```
this._http.post('/login',{email: 'email@example.com', password: '123'})
    .subscribe(response =>console.log(response), (error) => console.log(error));
```

And from back-end I send response as a text, for OK or Unauthorized, for OK i send back `String token == UUID.randomUUID().toString();`, for error I send back message like `String error = " Invalid credentials ";`, the problem is that the `console.log` works and print the text for success (token in this case), but in case error, its just prints: `Response with status: 200  for URL: null`.

If I change code to `JSON.stringify(error)` I get something like this:

```
{"_body":{},"status":401,"ok":false,"statusText":"Unauthorized","headers":{"null":["HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"],"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":["Origin"," X-Requested-With"," Content-Type"," Accept"," Referer"," User-Agent"],"Access-Control-Allow-Met
hods":["POST"," GET"," PUT"," DELETE"," OPTIONS"],"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":["*"],"Allow":["*"],"Content-Length":["36"],"Content-Type":["text/plain; charset=utf-8"],"Date":["Tue"," 23 Aug 2016 14:53:25 GMT"]},"type":2,"url":null}
```

As you can see the error test not even mentioned inside the Object !!

I tried to change the response for error from backend to return json like this:

```
{
   "message": "invalid email or password"
}
```

I can get the result inside `_body`, and I can only read it like this: `console.log(error._body.message)` ! but i feel its something wrong this way, and I don't want to response as a json in this case.

For angularjs (angular 1), its so simple just to print the response and everything is cool, while in angular 2 its a really problem.

What the problem, and how I can solve this issue without any refactor to backend?

**Edit:**

I'm using Angular 2.0.0-rc.4 and same for http : `"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4"

Answer (score 0):

Mothanfar
In my case I'm working with the Asp Web Api as back end,this thing is making me crazy as well, the only solution I found is transform in a json and read the message, I know is really ugly but works for me.
Regards.

```
CheckError(error: any) {
    let servermsg: any = JSON.parse(error._body)["ModelState"]["Login"][0];
    if (servermsg) {
        this.showMsg = true;
        this.msg = servermsg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning JSON object from the server, you may use the below code at client side:

```
let errMsg: ErrorMessage = err.json();
console.log(errMsg.message)

export class ErrorMessage {
  message:string;
}
```